# replace repmat with bsxfun in MATLAB

Tags: performance, matlab, for-loop, bsxfun

In the following function i want to make some changes to make it fast. By itself it is fast but i have to use it many times in a for loop so it takes long. I think if i replace the repmat with bsxfun will make it faster but i am not sure. How can i do these replacements

```
function out = lagcal(y1,y1k,source)
kn1 = y1(:);
kt1 = y1k(:);

kt1x = repmat(kt1,1,length(kt1));  

eq11 = 1./(prod(kt1x-kt1x'+eye(length(kt1))));
eq1 = eq11'*eq11;

dist = repmat(kn1,1,length(kt1))-repmat(kt1',length(kn1),1);
[fixi,fixj] = find(dist==0); dist(fixi,fixj)=eps;
mult = 1./(dist);

eq2 = prod(dist,2);
eq22 = repmat(eq2,1,length(kt1));
eq222 = eq22 .* mult; 

out = eq1 .* (eq222'*source*eq222);
end
```

Does it really speed up my function?

Comment: What are the sizes of `y1`, `y1k` and `source` How many calls are you making to this function? Maybe the bottleneck is the last line of multiple matrix multiplications?

Comment: I'd expect `repmat` to be just as optimized as `bsxfun`.

Comment: I'm curious about `repmat`'s performance, like @A.Donda has commented. How does profiler say?

Comment: @Divakar the size of y1, y1k ans source depends on the problem, more calls of the function smaller size of y1, y1k and source, as an example for a 4096 calls, they are 16*1,11*1 and 16*16 respectively.

Comment: @A.Donda yeah, the performance was not very better as i expected. the tic toc function says, for the first run, a 10.7 sec for the one with repmat and 10.4 for the bsxfun

Comment: @Divakar which one is faster, big matrices and vectors but less calls or small matrices and vector and more calls?

Comment: @Yvon Check out the benchmark results for the comparison across varying datasizes for this code - http://stackoverflow.com/a/24921975/3293881

Comment: @A.Donda Unless if you are talking about good sized data, that's not the case generally, specially if you are replicating arrays to perform operations later on that are accepted as function handles with `bsxfun`. Again this is on a general basis.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## Introduction and code changes

All the `repmat` usages used in the function code are to expand inputs to sizes so that  later on the mathemtical operations involving these inputs could be performed. This is tailor-made situation for bsxfun. Sadly though the real bottleneck of the function code seems to be something else.  Stay on as we discuss all the performance related aspects of the code.

Code with `repmat` replaced by `bsxfun` is presented next and the replaced codes
are kept as comments for comparison -

```
function out = lagcal(y1,y1k,source)

kn1 = y1(:);
kt1 = y1k(:);

%//kt1x = repmat(kt1,1,length(kt1));
%//eq11 = 1./(prod(kt1x-kt1x'+eye(length(kt1)))) %//'
eq11 = 1./prod(bsxfun(@minus,kt1,kt1.') + eye(numel(kt1))) %//'

eq1 = eq11'*eq11; %//'

%//dist = repmat(kn1,1,length(kt1))-repmat(kt1',length(kn1),1) %//'
dist = bsxfun(@minus,kn1,kt1.') %//'

[fixi,fixj] = find(dist==0); 

dist(fixi,fixj)=eps;
mult = 1./(dist);

eq2 = prod(dist,2);

%//eq22 = repmat(eq2,1,length(kt1));
%//eq222 = eq22 .* mult
eq222 = bsxfun(@times,eq2,mult)

out = eq1 .* (eq222'*source*eq222); %//'

return; %// Better this way to end a function
```

One more modification could be added here. In the last line, we could do
something like as shown below, but the timing results don't show a huge benefit
with it -

```
out = bsxfun(@times,eq11.',bsxfun(@times,eq11,eq222'*source*eq222))
```

This would avoid the calculation of `eq1` done earlier in the original code, so you would save little more time that way.

## Benchmarking

Benchmarking on the bsxfun modified portions of the code versus the original
repmat based codes is discussed next.

**Benchmarking Code**

```
N_arr = [50 100 200 500 1000 2000 3000]; %// array elements for N (datasize)
blocks = 3;
timeall = zeros(2,numel(N_arr),blocks);

for k1 = 1:numel(N_arr)
    N = N_arr(k1);
    y1 = rand(N,1);
    y1k = rand(N,1);
    source = rand(N);
    
    kn1 = y1(:);
    kt1 = y1k(:);
    
    %% Block 1 ----------------
    block = 1;
    f = @() block1_org(kt1);
    timeall(1,k1,block) = timeit(f);
    clear f
    
    f = @() block1_mod(kt1);
    timeall(2,k1,block) = timeit(f);
    eq11 = feval(f);
    clear f
    %% Block 1 ----------------
    
    eq1 = eq11'*eq11; %//'
    
    %% Block 2 ----------------
    block = 2;
    f = @() block2_org(kn1,kt1);
    timeall(1,k1,block) = timeit(f);
    clear f
    
    f = @() block2_mod(kn1,kt1);
    timeall(2,k1,block) = timeit(f);
    dist = feval(f);
    clear f
    %% Block 2 ----------------
    
    [fixi,fixj] = find(dist==0);
    
    dist(fixi,fixj)=eps;
    mult = 1./(dist);
    
    eq2 = prod(dist,2);
    
    %% Block 3 ----------------
    block = 3;
    f = @() block3_org(eq2,mult,length(kt1));
    timeall(1,k1,block) = timeit(f);
    clear f
    
    f = @() block3_mod(eq2,mult);
    timeall(2,k1,block) = timeit(f);
    clear f
    %% Block 3 ----------------
    
end

%// Display benchmark results
figure,
for k2 = 1:blocks
    subplot(blocks,1,k2),
    title(strcat('Block',num2str(k2),' results :'),'fontweight','bold'),hold on
    plot(N_arr,timeall(1,:,k2),'-ro')
    plot(N_arr,timeall(2,:,k2),'-kx')
    legend('REPMAT Method','BSXFUN Method')
    xlabel('Datasize (N) ->'),ylabel('Time(sec) ->')
end
```

**Associated functions**

```
function out = block1_org(kt1)
kt1x = repmat(kt1,1,length(kt1));
out = 1./(prod(kt1x-kt1x'+eye(length(kt1))));
return;

function out = block1_mod(kt1)
out = 1./prod(bsxfun(@minus,kt1,kt1.') + eye(numel(kt1)));
return;

function out = block2_org(kn1,kt1)
out = repmat(kn1,1,length(kt1))-repmat(kt1',length(kn1),1);
return;

function out = block2_mod(kn1,kt1)
out = bsxfun(@minus,kn1,kt1.');
return;

function out = block3_org(eq2,mult,length_kt1)
eq22 = repmat(eq2,1,length_kt1);
out = eq22 .* mult;
return;

function out = block3_mod(eq2,mult)
out = bsxfun(@times,eq2,mult);
return;
```

**Results**

[image]

## Conclusions

`bsxfun` based codes show around `2x` speedups over repmat based ones which is encouraging. But a profiling of the original code across a varying datasize show the multiple matrix multiplications in the final line seem to be occupying most of the runtime  for the function code, which are supposedly very efficient within MATLAB. Unless you have some way to avoid those multiplications by using some other mathematical technique, they look like the bottleneck.

Comment: you mean if i use the bsxfun for the last line it should do better?

Comment: @user3482383 Please read the edits, benchmarks, etc. presented for your benefit.

Comment: I wish all SO answers (including mine) were as good as this one.

Comment: according to the profiler, the time for computing eq11 and the last line are the most time consuming and the time for eq11 is a little more than the last line

Comment: @AnderBiguri It's the effect of on-the-face-big-fonts :) But yeah those benchmarks took some time to compile.

Comment: @user3482383 `y1, y1k and source, as an example for a 4096 calls, they are 16*1,11*1 and 16*16` right? Let me benchmark with these numbers.

Comment: @user3482383 Do you think the number of calls that is 4096 for your case now, could be reduced through vectorization?

Comment: @Divakar well, i split a big matrix into sqrt(4096) ones and use the chebyshev interpolation for each of them, i don't know putting them together give me the same result or not.

Comment: @Divakar thank you for your complete answer, the results and times recorded are for one call, right?

Comment: @user3482383 Yes, they are for each call but varying datasizes. Your datasize of 16, 11 are very small and as such they are not memory bound and thus, the matrix multiplications aren't the bottlenecks for your case.

Comment: @Divakar they are small but how about if they have to be called 4096 times? i say this because my tic toc time is much more than you showed me here

Comment: @user3482383 What I showed here is not just for one datasize (which is 16 in your case), but for a varying one as you can see in the codes and plots. Regarding speeding up your code when called for 4096 times,  let me ask you - Do all these three variables `y1, y1k and source` change across these 4096 iterations?

Comment: @Divakar No the size during these 4096 calls are the same but with different values. i mean for example is there any difference to call for a 100 times or with a smaller sizes but 50 calls?

Comment: @user3482383 So different values for all `y1, y1k and source` across these 4096 iterations? I am asking these because if any one of three variables have the same values across these iterations, then some sort of vectorization is possible on top of these 4096 calls to reduce the number of calls to 1 at least for few of the codes in the function, if not all. Sorry if this all sounds vague. I could explain better I guess if the entire program could be looked into.

Comment: @Divakar i have to check it completely, by the way thank you a lot for your time and help :)

Comment: @user3482383 This wasn't much helpful for your specific case of a small datasize to speed it up, but I think others on Stackoverflow would be benefited as a general case to similar problems. Maybe in some other aspects except getting a good speedup, it was helpful to you? If so, please consider accepting it.

Comment: Excellent edit! So the result is `bsxfun` is always better than `repmat`. Though the latter is more straightforward when doing first-stage development, obviously one needs to move his/her choice to achieve faster performance.

Comment: @Yvon Well OP is using the code on a small datasize of 16, for which `repmat` would have comparable performance against `bsxfun`. But if the datasize is decent sized, yes `bsxfun` is advised especially when you are performing operations like elementwise subtractions, multiplications, etc. (as used in the function code). The plots prove the point too.

Comment: @Divakar A little confusing now. Your results show `bsxfun` performs better than `repmat` AND elementwise operations _combined together_. Is it `repmat` or those basic things like `-` and `+` that slows down the code? It's hard to think about as element-wise binary operations appear almost everywhere, and replacing them with `bsxfun` sounds horrible.

Comment: @Yvon Well I have compared codes from OP where it has `repmat + some operation using input from repmat operation` against `bsxfun`. This `repmat + some operation` is essentially what `bsxfun` does in one go. That's why I said in my solution that this particular solution is tailor-made for `bsxfun`. You must not use `bsxfun` for elementwise operation, BUT use it when the inputs needs to be **expanded** for elementwise operations to be performed. The `sx` in `bsxfun` means `singleton expansion` is the essence of it. So, look at `bsxfun` as => `expansion and then elementwise operation` in one go.

Comment: @Yvon ... and look at `repmat` as the `expansion only` part. `bsxfun` is efficient because I am doing `expansion + elementwise operations` in one go instead of two steps with `repmat` AND THEN `elementwise operation`.

Comment: @Divakar I've just used your code to benchmark `repmat` and `bsxfun` with expansion only (`out = bsxfun(@minus,kt1,kt1'*0);`) and the speed is nearly the same, but `bsxfun` is anyway SLOWER. Better understanding now. Thanks!

Comment: @Yvon Exactly! As I said it's good only when performing expansion AND some operation using the expanded array. `bsxfun` is an awesome tool, it's understanding just opens gates for optimizations!