# How to calculate sum with two variables?

Tags: matlab

I'm trying to express a fuction with two variables, e.g:

[image: Fuction]

where `S(i,j)` is a matrix, `j=1:100`, `i=1:50`.

The denominator part is easy

```
for j=1:100
    M(j,1) = sum(S(j,:));
end
```

My problem is: I got confused when trying to contain `i` in the loop and get `M(i)`.

Comment: Just one little advice: try not to use the variables i and j in Matlab to refer to an index or something else. They are reserved for the imaginary-part of complex number. See here: https://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/imag.html

Answer (score 1):

First of all, in matlab you dont need the loop to get the sum for the denominator.

`sum()` can get the dimension along which you wish to sum over as the second input argument. Second, in order to get the other expression you simply need to create a temporary matrix for the multiplication in your matrix and then multiply elementwise. Lets call it J:

```
J = repmat(1:50,[100 1]);

M = sum(J.*S,2)./sum(S,2);
```

of course you can save the memory and simply not save J to memory:

```
M = sum(repmat(1:50,[100 1]).*S,2)./sum(S,2);
```

Comment: Consider using `bsxfun` instead of `repmat`. `M = sum(bsxfun(@times, (1:50).', S), 2) ./ sum(S, 2);` `bsxfun` has been known to outperform `repmat` based approaches: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24921424/replace-repmat-with-bsxfun-in-matlab